# Lighttpd equivalent of Apache Files directive?

Tags: lighttpd, rewrite

I'm trying to convert some rules and settings from Apache to lighttpd but i'm stuck with this Files rule:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/attachments>  
<Files ~ "\.(php\d*|cgi|pl|phtml)$">  
   order allow,deny  
   deny from all  
</Files>  
</Directory>
```

Looking at the documentation i could see that i can use the url.access-deny.

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/var/www/html/attachments" {
     url.access-deny = ("")
}

But don't know how to convert the Files part, any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$PHYSICAL["path"] =~ "\.(php\d*|cgi|pl|phtml)$" {
        access.deny-all = "enable" 
}
```